# How to get "jboss server binding address" from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I am running jboss server in linux box

I am creating three virtual ip in linux

10.3.2.123
10.3.2.124
10.3.2.125

I have created three jboss server instance and run separately

e.g.

> sh run.sh -b 10.3.2.123 -c node1
>
> sh run.sh -b 10.3.2.124 -c node2
>
> sh run.sh -b 10.3.2.125 -c node3

Application will be accesssed through loadbalanced server
loadbalanced server
loadbalanced server ip is    10.3.2.100
http://10.3.2.100/myapp/logon?user=test&pwd=test

In my logon servlet,
I need to get jboss "binding ip address" or "jboss server info" in my  servlet code
[color=red][/color][size=12][/size][size=12][/size]
Please share me your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need this in the logon servlet  (because it is running in a JBoss instance, right ?) but you can get it like this:

> System.getProperty("jboss.bind.address");

//Nicholas